# The limit in law of a sequence of normal distributions is normal

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, weak-convergence

Let $ \{ \xi_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of normal random variables, where $ \xi_n\sim\mathcal{N}(\alpha_n, \sigma_n^2)$ and $\xi_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} \xi$.
I need to prove, that $\xi$ is also a normal random variable, can anyone help?

Comment: Use characteristic functions.

Comment: @Stefan: That's part of the conclusion.